# Youtube Zend Api Function Interrupts Script

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube

This is the code:

```
...
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Uri_Http');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($id_video);
....
```

In this script's few lines, SOMETIMES  (I didn't understand why this keep happening just some times, and not in others, seemingly random)  Zend_Gdata_YouTube() or getVideoEntry($id_video) doesn't return, and the script dies. In the script's folder there are no log files, so I don't understand what does it happen at run time. Any help or suggest would be appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, but with uploading youtube videos. By digging around in the Zend files, I found where the script dies. It is in `Zend/Gdata/HttpAdapterStreamingSocket.php`:

```
while ($chunk !== FALSE) {
    if (! @fwrite($this->socket, $chunk)) {
        require_once 'Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception(
            'Error writing request to server');
    }
    $chunk = $body->read(self::CHUNK_SIZE);
}
```

By removing the `@` from `fwrite`, I got the maximum execution time exceeded error. By disabling the execution time limit for the loop, the error didn't come up again:

```
$executionTime = ini_get('max_execution_time');
set_time_limit(0);
while ($chunk !== FALSE) {
    if (! fwrite($this->socket, $chunk)) {
        require_once 'Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception(
            'Error writing request to server');
    }
    $chunk = $body->read(self::CHUNK_SIZE);
}
set_time_limit($executionTime);
```

This may not be your exact problem, but try to look in the Zend files for @fwrite calls and do the same thing, because your script is probably dying while writing chunks to the socket, and on a function that suppresses errors.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, It's related to uploading really huge files, I only see this error on uploading 3GB +, anyway to solve it ?