# Zend Youtube Api keeps returning exception

Tags: zend-framework, exception, youtube, gdata

Whenever I try to fetch some data from youtube, it keeps returning the "Error writing request to server" as an exception message. I'm using zend 1.12.3 and I tried some of the following, which by the way worked like 1-2 months ago, but now apparently they don't

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion();
$url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?orderby=relevance&start-index=1&time=this_month&max-results=15&q=pranks+epic+funny+fun+cool';
$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($url);
```

or

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->videoQuery = 'cat';
$query->startIndex = 10;
$query->maxResults = 20;
$query->orderBy = 'viewCount';

$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query);
```

Both of them returning the exception I mentioned. However, this

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/standardfeeds/top_rated?time=today';
$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($url);
```

works and doesn't return an error.

I tried the same thing locally and on a server, same error. Is anyone else getting the same error? Is there possibly something wrong with youtube?

Comment: I've tried all the 3 code snippets and all worked fine, with and exception that you're missing the argument for the `setMajorProtocolVersion` function call on the 1st example. With that said, I don't think you're problem as anything to do with your code. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11467791/2000503) as it might shed some light on your real problem.

Comment: Actually I tried something that fixed my problem, can you maybe explain me why this is happening? I've added it as an answer below.

Comment: I've read how you solved the problem, but I don't really have a clue. You should try to debug as stated in the answer I posted in my previous comment. Removing the `@` from the `fwrite` instruction in the `Zend/Gdata/HttpAdapterStreamingSocket.php` file should show the real error that's occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason, when i changed the $url in the first example from "https://....." to "http://....." it worked.

This is weird as https is supposed to work, but I leave it here for anyone that might have the same problem.

Comment: Raise an issue with YouTube about this. Don't leave it hanging like this - if youtube has a problem they need to solve it especially when it is something like encryption.

Comment: Yes you're right, I reported the issue today and await for a response. Thanks for the reminder!